# Обособление названий в качестве приложений

Tags: пунктуация

Предложения носящие пояснительный характер, обычно выделяются двумя тире. В то же время при обособлении приложений, выражающих более конкретное значение по отношению к определяемому слову, второе тире опускается. Если приложение - это название, можно ли сказать, что оно выражает более конкретное значение, или в данном случае оно остается пояснением? Здесь также возможны и скобки. Не говорит ли это в пользу обособления двумя тире?

Заказчик, приобретая лицензию на определенный процесс переработки сырья, не всегда задумывается над тем, что практически все лицензиары указывают в качестве норм проектирования иностранные стандарты — ASМE, EN и применение импортных марок сталей, оговоренных этими стандартами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь возможно два решения, но мне кажется, что больше подойдет вариант с обособлением двумя тире, в этом случае приложение имеет **добавочный** характер и **выделяется паузами**:

Заказчик, приобретая лицензию на определенный процесс переработки сырья, не всегда задумывается над тем, что практически все лицензиары указывают в качестве норм проектирования иностранные стандарты — ASМE, EN — и применение импортных марок сталей, оговоренных этими стандартами.

Пояснение

В предложениях с однородными членами при наличии союзов И, ДА=И возможны два варианта решения. Одно тире ставится при тесной связи приложения и однородного члена, а два тире используются  в тех случаях, когда приложение является добавочным сообщением.

Практические примеры

**Одно тире**  при тесной связи приложения и определяемого слова (нет пауз, встроенные приложения): Я начал говорить об условиях, о неравенстве, о людях – жертвах жизни и о людях – владыках её.

**Два тире**, добавочное сообщение (паузы, интонация исключения): Ловили рыбу бреднем – маленьким неводом –  да вершами-ловушками.

Comment: Значит постановка одного тире не является ошибкой? Ведь смотрела же на этот параграф у Розенталя уже десять раз, а то, что это однородные члены, упустила из виду. Я больше смотрела на характер приложений. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

> Заказчик, приобретая лицензию на определенный процесс переработки
>   сырья, не всегда задумывается над тем, что практически все лицензиары
>   указывают в качестве норм проектирования иностранные стандарты — ASМE,
>   EN — и применение импортных марок сталей, оговоренных этими
>   стандартами.

По-моему, здесь какая-то ошибка.

С каким словом связано в этом предложении слово "применение"? Со словом "указывают"? *Лицензиары **указывают применение***?

Может, лучше написать как-то так:

*"…практически все лицензиары указывают в качестве норм проектирования иностранные стандарты — ASМE, EN,  **которыми/в которых**  оговорено применение…"* ?

Не знаю, какое место в техпроцессе переработки сырья отведено сталям, *оговорённым* стандартами, потому не могу предложить какое-либо более-менее приемлемое продолжение. Но в том, что исходный вариант плох,  практически уверен.